# Flask Python - How to pass variable from one method to another

Tags: python, function, flask

I have a flask app and I need to pass variables from one function to another. The requirement here is I need to pass the value of 'skill' from index() to get_image(), any idea on how this can be achieved?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    data = json.loads(request.get_data())
    skill = data['conversation']['skill']


@app.route("/get-image/<image_name>")
def get_image(image_name):
    if skill == 'getpositions':
        # some code
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try use `flask sessions` for example:

```
from flask import Flask, session

...

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    data = json.loads(request.get_data())
    skill = data['conversation']['skill']
    session['skill'] = skill

@app.route("/get-image/<image_name>")
def get_image(image_name):
    if session['skill'] == 'getpositions':
    #some code
```

Check the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/).